# How can I call the boolean from c# to Javascript Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I was trying to call the `boolean` from my Controller which is `true`, But when I call it now on my `Javascript ajax` I can't get it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Shop/Accessories",
    contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "html",
    success: (function (result) {
        if (result) { //If I do result == true : still not working
            $('#owl1').html(result)
            $('#owl1').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                nav: false,
                dots: false,
                autoplay: false,
                margin: 10,
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    600: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    1000: {
                        items: 4
                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            $(".noItem1").html(result);
        }
    }),
    error: (function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
})
```

I am using a `dataType: html` for the `return View` when the database doesn't have any `data`

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            string command = "select item_image, item_name, item_price item_number, item_type, date_added from cooking_items";

            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                SqlDataReader Creader1;
                Creader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (Creader1.HasRows == true)
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return View("Cooking", dt);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Cooking"); //When there's no data, these is the one who should call my ajax.
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are returning html from your action, what do you expect that the "if (result)" -condition will do? Maybe you want to change the return type to json like {"hasData": true/false, "html": "my html"}. Ps. why are you opening/closing your connection so many times? You only need one open and there is no need to close it at all since the disposing of SqlConnection will already do that. Also SqlDatareader is implementing iDisposable so you should use using-statement with that also.

Comment: No. I was returning view with table, if the `DataReader` didn't find any `rows` on `sql` It should proceed to else in my `viewport`

Comment: The thing is, even there's no `rows` it still launch the `owl-carousel` with the `else` statement

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said not sure which part you did not understand. You are returning html (view) in both cases. So your if cannot work, result will always be "true" since that contains just a html string. Hence the code inside the if will always execute.